# wierd issue with pymongo, always get NoNe for every query

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I cannot figure out what the problem is with this code. My database initializes properly, i know that because the insert method works - i see the insertions appear in the mongo shell of the server. However, the find methods always return None for some reason.

```
import pymongo
```

class Database(object):

```
url = "mongodb://192.168.2.104:27017"
DATABASE = None

@staticmethod
def initialize():
    client = pymongo.MongoClient(Database.url)
    Database.DATABASE = client["fullstack"]

@staticmethod
def insert(collection, data):
    Database.DATABASE[collection].insert(data)

@staticmethod
def find(collection, query):
    Database.DATABASE[collection].find(query)
```

now suppose there is a record in my "posts" collection with attribute "blog_id": "123" - i know because it pops up when i do db.posts.find({"blog_id": "123"}) in mongo shell. However,

```
from database import Database
Database.initialize()

post = Database.find("posts", {"blog_id": "123"})

for x in post:
    print x
```

This code always returns None. What could be going wrong here? I am running mongo in a remote VM with only terminal ubuntu. Problem with code? or maybe there is read permission problem in my VM server? Thanks in advance

Comment: your `find` function does not return anything, so `post` will be `None` - try `return Database.DATABASE[collection].find(query)`

Comment: holy optical illusions T_T  wracking my heads with permissions and stuff while i missed return on 3 functions Lol.  Thanks man.